# Flex 3 columns with space between

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a container with dynamic width that will always have 3 columns per row, first column stick to the left, second column in the center of the entire row and third column stick to the right. Is there an automatic way to achieve this?

```
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

```
|x     x     x|
|x     x     x|
|x            |
```

I was trying

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
```

and for items

```
flex: 1 0 30%
```

but the `30%` makes the items wider like:

```
|x   x   x   |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `justify-content: space-between;` inorder to make it like that.

```css
.container { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;  flex: 0 0 30%; justify-content:space-between;} 
.box {background: #efefef; width: 30%; border:1px solid #fff; height: 150px; }
```

```html
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box box_1">Box 1</div>
        <div class="box box_2">Box 2</div>
        <div class="box box_3">Box 3</div>
        <div class="box box_1">Box 1</div>
        <div class="box box_2">Box 2</div>
        <div class="box box_3">Box 3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I edited my post - inside container there is a lot more divs, not three

Comment: I have updated my answer too. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you know there will ALWAYS be 3 columns, you could just use `align-items` on the column to position **flex-start**, **center**, and **flex-end**.

```css
.row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}

.col {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-grow: 1;
   border: 1px solid deeppink;
}

.col:nth-child(1) {
   align-items: flex-start;
}
.col:nth-child(2) {
   align-items: center;
}
.col:nth-child(3) {
   align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">COLUMN</div>
   <div class="col">COLUMN</div>
   <div class="col">COLUMN</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">COLUMN</div>
   <div class="col">COLUMN</div>
   <div class="col">COLUMN</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">COLUMN</div>
   <div class="col">COLUMN</div>
   <div class="col">COLUMN</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try with 6 or 9 columns instead of 3.

Comment: The question says `will always have 3 columns per row`...

Comment: Right, so add another row with three more columns

Comment: Ok, I added more rows....